# Deploy components into Common/ Shared folder

Tags: jss

We are looking for some suggestions on the folder structure to make the components shared across multiple sites. At the moment if we deploy the components to Sitecore, it’s getting created under the specific project folder for the templates and renderings.

[image]

Is it possible to deploy the components into Common Section or a Shared components folder under Templates and Renderings? So that it can be shared across `multiple sites/applications`
Also would like to know, whether the approach we are looking for is right?

Answer (score 1):

If instead of vanilla JSS you would go with SXA JSS sites (SXA 1.9 has builtin support of JSS) then all of the components are shared across Tenant. This means you can use them in all sites of that tenant (just take care of placeholder settings items). For more details take a look here: [Managing JSS apps with SXA](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/managing-jss-apps-with-sxa.html).

Besides this integration with SXA will also give you:

- SXA site management for JSS apps
- Cross-site presentation sharing using page designs and partial designs
- Cross-site content sharing
- Cross-site linking